# ¿porqué no funciona este código script.run al recibir arreglos en Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, script, function

Esta función devuelve correctamente el registro de la hoja:

```
function buscarRegistro(id) {
  console.log("ID recibido en buscar :", id);
  var datosHoja = hoja.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Buscar la fila con la identificación 
  for (var i = 0; i < datosHoja.length; i++) {
    if (datosHoja[i][2] === id) { // El campo identificación está en la tercera columna
      return datosHoja[i];
    }
  }
  // Si no se encontró el usuario
  return [];
}
```

pero ésta, que es la función que la llama, con la cual busco mostrar los valores en el formulario, recibe undefined:

```
function buscarRegistro() {
  var id = document.getElementById("documento").value;
  console.log(id)
  google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler( datosRecibidos =>{
        console.log(datosRecibidos)
        if (datosRecibidos) {
          document.getElementById('perfilProductivo').value = datosRecibidos[0];
          document.getElementById('participante').value = datosRecibidos[1];
          document.getElementById('fecha').value = datosRecibidos[3];
          document.getElementById('sociosClaves').value = datosRecibidos[4];
          document.getElementById('propuestaValor').value = datosRecibidos[5];
          document.getElementById('segmentoClientes').value = datosRecibidos[6];
          document.getElementById('mediosPago').value = datosRecibidos[7];
          document.getElementById('estructuraCostos').value = datosRecibidos[8];
          document.getElementById('actividadesClaves').value = datosRecibidos[9];
          document.getElementById('relacionCliente').value = datosRecibidos[10];
          document.getElementById('recursosClaves').value = datosRecibidos[11];
          document.getElementById('canales').value = datosRecibidos[12];
          document.getElementById('fuentesIngreso').value = datosRecibidos[13];
          // Asignar el valor del documento después de haber asignado los demás valores
         // document.getElementById('documento').value = datosRecibidos.[2];
        }else{
          console.error("Datos recibidos son nulos o vacíos")
        }
      })
      .withFailureHandler(function (error) {
          console.error("Error del servidor:", error);
          mostrarModal("Error al buscar el usuario. Detalles: " + error.message);
      })
      .buscarRegistro(id);
}
```

He buscado por todos los lados, he puesto logs por muchos lados y no encuentro la razón del error.  Alguien me puede echar una mano, por favor, para identificar dónde está el error, lo agradecería.

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué es lo que aparece cono `undefined` exactamente?

Comment: Hola, en console.log(datosRecibidos) de la línea 6 de la 2a función aparece en la consola como indefinido.  He verificado que return datosHoja[i] en la primera función envía los datos correctamente, pero por alguna razón la función que la invoca no los recibe o los recibe mal.

Comment: Por favor, revisa [la documentación](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication?hl=es-419#success_handlers). Dentro del HTML debes poner una función `onSuccess` que va a recibir como parámetro  la respuesta de tu función que busca los registros. Y, si necesitas modificar la interfaz, lo harás dentro de `onSuccess` tal y como muestra el ejemplo de la doc. Ahí hace algo sencillo, que es buscar la cantidad de emails no leídos. Solamente adáptalo a tu contexto. Tienes todo mezclado y así no funcionará, debes hacerlo con devolución de llamada.

Comment: Precisamente, en el script del html incluyo la función buscarRegistro() con los eventos .withSuccessHandler y .withFailureHandler, con los que busco manejar el éxito o error de la función, pese a esto, sigue recibiendo el array vacío a pesar que he verificado que contiene la fila encontrada

Comment: he modificado la función que llama , de la siguiente forma:  
function buscarRegistro() {
  var id = document.getElementById("documento").value;
  console.log(id)
  
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
    .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .obtenerRegistroPorId(id);
}

Comment: ¿Has probado llamar a la función `onSuccess`? Puede que la API tenga una convención y que la función que devuelve la llamada exitosa deba llamarse de ese modo sí o sí.

Comment: Claro, he modificado el código y ha quedado como muestro a continuación, y aún no funciona: function buscarRegistro() {
  var id = document.getElementById("documento").value;
  console.log(id)
  
  google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
    .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .obtenerRegistroPorId(id);
} y distribuí las acciones del éxito o error en las correspondientes, y aún